# How to process a json and return a new json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

What I'm trying to make is an angular app that reads in a json file and displays them, and allows users to edit the json file using html controls. Then, the user can create a new json object based on their selections and display it.

Here is a picture to help describe what I'm trying to do:

[image]

So, the user sees this, they make certain selections, e.g. lock them or delete them, then they hit create, and a new json file is returned based on which objects they have chosen to lock or delete.

At the moment I just have a standard angular app which gets and displays the json:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data.records;
  });

  $scope.createJson = function(){
    // Create new json file
  };
});
```

The body of my html/my angular app looks like this at the moment:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in myData">
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.City }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="lock" value="{{x.Name}}"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="{{x.Name}}"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button ng-click="createJson()">Create</button>

</div>
```

Baiscally, I'm not sure if my approach is correct at the moment, and if it is, I don't really know what my next step is.

P.S. this is just test data I am using for the sake of learning/testing, it is not my data, I got it from: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php

Comment: Please share html which produce above html in image.Also your controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an appropriate solution by simply creating a new and empty JSON object:

```
var newJson = [];
```

and populating it by looping through my original one and using array.push() to add the selected entries:

```
for (var person in $scope.myData){
  if($scope.myData[person].Delete === false || $scope.myData[person].Lock === true){
    newJson.push($scope.myData[person])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
JSON.stringify($scope.myData)
```

or

```
angular.toJson($scope.myData)
```

this will give you string representation of your data object. The rest is up to you, you may assign it to textarea, post it back to server (in this case, you most likely won't even need to encode it before) etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="lock" value="{{x.Name}}"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="{{x.Name}}"></td>
```

as

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="lock" ng-model="x.Name"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="delete" ng-model="x.Name"></td>
```

(Actually I didn't understand why you use string in checkbox. It should be boolean value).

By this way any change will change your $scope.myData.

On create you should take info from user and create a new JsonObject like

```
var newObject = {
    Name: 'Name Surname',
    City: 'City',
    Country: 'Country'
}
```

And add this to your myData with;

```
$scope.myData.push(newObject);
```